# Add a header before text file on save in Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I have some spark code to process a csv file. It does some transformation on it. I now want to save this RDD as a csv file and add a header. Each line of this RDD is already formatted correctly.

I am not sure how to do it. I wanted to do a union with the header string and my RDD but the header string is not an RDD so it does not work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can make an RDD out of your header line and then `union` it, yes:

```
val rdd: RDD[String] = ...
val header: RDD[String] = sc.parallelize(Array("my,header,row"))
header.union(rdd).saveAsTextFile(...)
```

Then you end up with a bunch of `part-xxxxx` files that you merge.

The problem is that I don't think you're guaranteed that the header will be the first partition and therefore end up in `part-00000` and at the top of your file. In practice, I'm pretty sure it will.

More reliable would be to use Hadoop commands like `hdfs` to merge the `part-xxxxx` files, and as part of the command, just throw in the header line from a file.

Comment: In Spark 1.6.2 running in distributed mode, union did not put header on top for me. Here is my code snippet :-

`val header = sc.parallelize(Array('col1','col2'), 1)
    header.union(
      rdd.map(_.toString))
.repartition(1).saveAsTextFile(outputLocation)`

Comment: same issue for me... `union()` is not guaranteed to preserve order. looking for a workaround now, looks like sorting the RDD might help

Answer (score 0):

Some help on writing it without Union(Supplied the header at the time of merge)

```
val fileHeader ="This is header"
val fileHeaderStream: InputStream = new  ByteArrayInputStream(fileHeader.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
val output = IOUtils.copyBytes(fileHeaderStream,out,conf,false)
```

Now loop over you file parts to write the complete file using

```
val in: DataInputStream = ...<data input stream from file >
 IOUtils.copyBytes(in, output, conf, false)
```

This made sure for me that header always comes as first line even when you use coalasec/repartition for efficient writing

Answer (score 0):

```
def addHeaderToRdd(sparkCtx: SparkContext, lines: RDD[String], header: String): RDD[String] = {

    val headerRDD = sparkCtx.parallelize(List((-1L, header)))     // We index the header with -1, so that the sort will put it on top.

    val pairRDD = lines.zipWithIndex()

    val pairRDD2 = pairRDD.map(t => (t._2, t._1))

    val allRDD = pairRDD2.union(headerRDD)

    val allSortedRDD = allRDD.sortByKey()

    return allSortedRDD.values
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Slightly diff approach with Spark SQL

> From Question: I now want to save this RDD as a CSV file and add a header. Each line of this RDD is already formatted correctly.

**With Spark 2.x you have several options to [convert RDD to DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42469625/1592191)**

```
val rdd = .... //Assume rdd properly formatted with case class or tuple
val df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd).toDF("col1", "col2", ... "coln")

df.write
  .format("csv")
  .option("header", "true")  //adds header to file
  .save("hdfs://location/to/save/csv")
```

Now we can even use Spark SQL DataFrame to load, transform and save CSV file

Answer (score 0):

```
spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(SqlHelper.getARow(temRet.columns, 
temRet.columns.length))).union(temRet.rdd).map(x => 
x.mkString("\x01")).coalesce(1, true).saveAsTextFile(retPath)


object SqlHelper {
//create one row
def getARow(x: Array[String], size: Int): Row = {
var columnArray = new Array[String](size)
for (i <- 0 to (size - 1)) {
  columnArray(i) = x(i).toString()
}
Row.fromSeq(columnArray)
}
}
```

Comment: can someone write this in Java