# How to convert rdd object to dataframe in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

How can I convert an RDD (`org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]`) to a Dataframe `org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame`. I converted a dataframe to rdd using `.rdd`. After processing it I want it back in dataframe. How can I do this ?

Comment: way to achieve this in [Spark 2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42469625/1592191)

Answer (score 99, accepted):

[`SparkSession`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession.html#createDataFrame(rowRDD:org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD%5Borg.apache.spark.sql.Row%5D,schema:org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) has a number of `createDataFrame` methods that create a `DataFrame` given an `RDD`. I imagine one of these will work for your context.

For example:

```
def createDataFrame(rowRDD: RDD[Row], schema: StructType): DataFrame
```

> Creates a DataFrame from an RDD containing Rows using the given
> schema.

Answer (score 120):

This code works perfectly from **Spark 2.x with Scala 2.11**

Import necessary classes

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Row, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{DoubleType, StringType, StructField, StructType}
```

Create `SparkSession` Object, and Here it's `spark`

```
val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder.master("local").getOrCreate
val sc = spark.sparkContext // Just used to create test RDDs
```

Let's an `RDD` to make it `DataFrame`

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(
  Seq(
    ("first", Array(2.0, 1.0, 2.1, 5.4)),
    ("test", Array(1.5, 0.5, 0.9, 3.7)),
    ("choose", Array(8.0, 2.9, 9.1, 2.5))
  )
)
```

##Method 1
Using `SparkSession.createDataFrame(RDD obj)`.

```
val dfWithoutSchema = spark.createDataFrame(rdd)

dfWithoutSchema.show()
+------+--------------------+
|    _1|                  _2|
+------+--------------------+
| first|[2.0, 1.0, 2.1, 5.4]|
|  test|[1.5, 0.5, 0.9, 3.7]|
|choose|[8.0, 2.9, 9.1, 2.5]|
+------+--------------------+
```

##Method 2
Using `SparkSession.createDataFrame(RDD obj)` and specifying column names.

```
val dfWithSchema = spark.createDataFrame(rdd).toDF("id", "vals")

dfWithSchema.show()
+------+--------------------+
|    id|                vals|
+------+--------------------+
| first|[2.0, 1.0, 2.1, 5.4]|
|  test|[1.5, 0.5, 0.9, 3.7]|
|choose|[8.0, 2.9, 9.1, 2.5]|
+------+--------------------+
```

##Method 3 (Actual answer to the question)
This way requires the input `rdd` should be of type `RDD[Row]`.

```
val rowsRdd: RDD[Row] = sc.parallelize(
  Seq(
    Row("first", 2.0, 7.0),
    Row("second", 3.5, 2.5),
    Row("third", 7.0, 5.9)
  )
)
```

create the schema

```
val schema = new StructType()
  .add(StructField("id", StringType, true))
  .add(StructField("val1", DoubleType, true))
  .add(StructField("val2", DoubleType, true))
```

Now apply both `rowsRdd` and `schema` to `createDataFrame()`

```
val df = spark.createDataFrame(rowsRdd, schema)

df.show() 
+------+----+----+
|    id|val1|val2|
+------+----+----+
| first| 2.0| 7.0|
|second| 3.5| 2.5|
| third| 7.0| 5.9|
+------+----+----+
```

Comment: Thank you for showing the different ways of using createDataFrame in an understandable way

Comment: the third method is helpful on data bricks as others are not working and giving an error

Answer (score 68):

Assuming your RDD[row] is called rdd, you can use:

```
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc) 
import sqlContext.implicits._
rdd.toDF()
```

Comment: I think it doesn't work for RDD[Row]. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Since Spark 2.0 SQLContext is replaced by SparkSession, but the class is kept in the code base for backward compatibility [(scaladoc).](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/SQLContext.html) Using it throws deprecation warning.

Comment: this doesn't work. RDD[Row] doesnt give you that option. Need t o convert it to tuple of case class RDD

Answer (score 22):

*Note: This answer was originally posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37011267/)*

*I am posting this answer because I would like to share additional details about the available options that I did not find in the other answers*

---

To create a DataFrame from an RDD of Rows, there are two main options:

**1)** As already pointed out, you could use `toDF()` which can be imported by `import sqlContext.implicits._`. However, this approach only works for the following types of RDDs:

- `RDD[Int]`
- `RDD[Long]`
- `RDD[String]`
- `RDD[T <: scala.Product]`

(source: [Scaladoc](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$implicits$) of the `SQLContext.implicits` object)

The last signature actually means that it can work for an RDD of tuples or an RDD of case classes (because tuples and case classes are subclasses of `scala.Product`).

So, to use this approach for an `RDD[Row]`, you have to map it to an `RDD[T <: scala.Product]`. This can be done by mapping each row to a custom case class or to a tuple, as in the following code snippets:

```
val df = rdd.map({ 
  case Row(val1: String, ..., valN: Long) => (val1, ..., valN)
}).toDF("col1_name", ..., "colN_name")
```

or

```
case class MyClass(val1: String, ..., valN: Long = 0L)
val df = rdd.map({ 
  case Row(val1: String, ..., valN: Long) => MyClass(val1, ..., valN)
}).toDF("col1_name", ..., "colN_name")
```

The main drawback of this approach (in my opinion) is that you have to explicitly set the schema of the resulting DataFrame in the map function, column by column. Maybe this can be done programatically if you don't know the schema in advance, but things can get a little messy there. So, alternatively, there is another option:

---

**2)** You can use `createDataFrame(rowRDD: RDD[Row], schema: StructType)` as in the accepted answer, which is available in the [SQLContext](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext) object. Example for converting an RDD of an old DataFrame:

```
val rdd = oldDF.rdd
val newDF = oldDF.sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, oldDF.schema)
```

Note that there is no need to explicitly set any schema column. We reuse the old DF's schema, which is of `StructType` class and can be easily extended. However, this approach sometimes is not possible, and in some cases can be less efficient than the first one.

Comment: Thanks for the detail `import sqlContext.implicits.`

Comment: In future, please don't post identical answers to multiple questions. If the questions are duplicats, post one good answer, then vote or flag to close the other question as a duplicate. If the question is not a duplicate, *tailor your answers to the question.* See [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 15):

Suppose you have a `DataFrame` and you want to do some modification on the fields data by converting it to `RDD[Row]`.

```
val aRdd = aDF.map(x=>Row(x.getAs[Long]("id"),x.getAs[List[String]]("role").head))
```

To convert back to `DataFrame` from `RDD` we need to define the *structure type* of the `RDD`.

If the datatype was `Long`  then it will become as `LongType` in structure.

If `String` then `StringType` in structure.

```
val aStruct = new StructType(Array(StructField("id",LongType,nullable = true),StructField("role",StringType,nullable = true)))
```

Now you can convert the RDD to DataFrame using the *createDataFrame* method.

```
val aNamedDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(aRdd,aStruct)
```

Answer (score 9):

Method 1: (Scala)

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
import sqlContext.implicits._
val df_2 = sc.parallelize(Seq((1L, 3.0, "a"), (2L, -1.0, "b"), (3L, 0.0, "c"))).toDF("x", "y", "z")
```

Method 2: (Scala)

```
case class temp(val1: String,val3 : Double) 

val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  Row("foo",  0.5), Row("bar",  0.0)
))
val rows = rdd.map({case Row(val1:String,val3:Double) => temp(val1,val3)}).toDF()
rows.show()
```

Method 1: (Python)

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
l = [('Alice',2)]
Person = Row('name','age')
rdd = sc.parallelize(l)
person = rdd.map(lambda r:Person(*r))
df2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(person)
df2.show()
```

Method 2: (Python)

```
from pyspark.sql.types import * 
l = [('Alice',2)]
rdd = sc.parallelize(l)
schema =  StructType([StructField ("name" , StringType(), True) , 
StructField("age" , IntegerType(), True)]) 
df3 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, schema) 
df3.show()
```

Extracted the value from the row object and then applied the case class to convert rdd to DF

```
val temp1 = attrib1.map{case Row ( key: Int ) => s"$key" }
val temp2 = attrib2.map{case Row ( key: Int) => s"$key" }

case class RLT (id: String, attrib_1 : String, attrib_2 : String)
import hiveContext.implicits._

val df = result.map{ s => RLT(s(0),s(1),s(2)) }.toDF
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is a simple example of converting your List into Spark RDD and then converting that Spark RDD into Dataframe.

Please note that I have used Spark-shell's scala REPL to execute following code, Here sc is an instance of SparkContext which is implicitly available in Spark-shell. Hope it answer your question.

```
scala> val numList = List(1,2,3,4,5)
numList: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> val numRDD = sc.parallelize(numList)
numRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int] = ParallelCollectionRDD[80] at parallelize at <console>:28

scala> val numDF = numRDD.toDF
numDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [_1: int]

scala> numDF.show
+---+
| _1|
+---+
|  1|
|  2|
|  3|
|  4|
|  5|
+---+
```

Comment: A fun fact: this stops working, when your List is of Double, instead of int (or Long, String,<: Product).

Comment: Does not answer the OP : which talks about RDD[Row]

Answer (score 4):

On newer versions of spark (2.0+)

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._

val dfSchema = Seq("col1", "col2", "col3")
rdd.toDF(dfSchema: _*)
```

Comment: sparkSession is just a wrapper for sqlContext, hiveContext

Answer (score 1):

```
One needs to create a schema, and attach it to the Rdd.
```

Assuming val spark is a product of a SparkSession.builder...

```
    import org.apache.spark._
    import org.apache.spark.sql._       
    import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

    /* Lets gin up some sample data:
     * As RDD's and dataframes can have columns of differing types, lets make our
     * sample data a three wide, two tall, rectangle of mixed types.
     * A column of Strings, a column of Longs, and a column of Doubules 
     */
    val arrayOfArrayOfAnys = Array.ofDim[Any](2,3)
    arrayOfArrayOfAnys(0)(0)="aString"
    arrayOfArrayOfAnys(0)(1)=0L
    arrayOfArrayOfAnys(0)(2)=3.14159
    arrayOfArrayOfAnys(1)(0)="bString"
    arrayOfArrayOfAnys(1)(1)=9876543210L
    arrayOfArrayOfAnys(1)(2)=2.71828

    /* The way to convert an anything which looks rectangular, 
     * (Array[Array[String]] or Array[Array[Any]] or Array[Row], ... ) into an RDD is to 
     * throw it into sparkContext.parallelize.
     * http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkContext shows
     * the parallelize definition as 
     *     def parallelize[T](seq: Seq[T], numSlices: Int = defaultParallelism)
     * so in our case our ArrayOfArrayOfAnys is treated as a sequence of ArraysOfAnys.
     * Will leave the numSlices as the defaultParallelism, as I have no particular cause to change it. 
     */
    val rddOfArrayOfArrayOfAnys=spark.sparkContext.parallelize(arrayOfArrayOfAnys)

    /* We'll be using the sqlContext.createDataFrame to add a schema our RDD.
     * The RDD which goes into createDataFrame is an RDD[Row] which is not what we happen to have.
     * To convert anything one tall and several wide into a Row, one can use Row.fromSeq(thatThing.toSeq)
     * As we have an RDD[somethingWeDontWant], we can map each of the RDD rows into the desired Row type. 
     */     
    val rddOfRows=rddOfArrayOfArrayOfAnys.map(f=>
        Row.fromSeq(f.toSeq)
    )

    /* Now to construct our schema. This needs to be a StructType of 1 StructField per column in our dataframe.
     * https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField shows the definition as
     *   case class StructField(name: String, dataType: DataType, nullable: Boolean = true, metadata: Metadata = Metadata.empty)
     * Will leave the two default values in place for each of the columns:
     *        nullability as true, 
     *        metadata as an empty Map[String,Any]
     *   
     */

    val schema = StructType(
        StructField("colOfStrings", StringType) ::
        StructField("colOfLongs"  , LongType  ) ::
        StructField("colOfDoubles", DoubleType) ::
        Nil
    )

    val df=spark.sqlContext.createDataFrame(rddOfRows,schema)
    /*
     *      +------------+----------+------------+
     *      |colOfStrings|colOfLongs|colOfDoubles|
     *      +------------+----------+------------+
     *      |     aString|         0|     3.14159|
     *      |     bString|9876543210|     2.71828|
     *      +------------+----------+------------+
    */ 
    df.show
```

Same steps, but with fewer val declarations:

```
    val arrayOfArrayOfAnys=Array(
        Array("aString",0L         ,3.14159),
        Array("bString",9876543210L,2.71828)
    )

    val rddOfRows=spark.sparkContext.parallelize(arrayOfArrayOfAnys).map(f=>Row.fromSeq(f.toSeq))

    /* If one knows the datatypes, for instance from JDBC queries as to RDBC column metadata:
     * Consider constructing the schema from an Array[StructField].  This would allow looping over 
     * the columns, with a match statement applying the appropriate sql datatypes as the second
     *  StructField arguments.   
     */
    val sf=new Array[StructField](3)
    sf(0)=StructField("colOfStrings",StringType)
    sf(1)=StructField("colOfLongs"  ,LongType  )
    sf(2)=StructField("colOfDoubles",DoubleType)        
    val df=spark.sqlContext.createDataFrame(rddOfRows,StructType(sf.toList))
    df.show
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to explain the solution using the **word count problem**.
 1. Read the file using sc

2. Produce word count
3. Methods to create DF

   - rdd.toDF method
   - rdd.toDF("word","count")

     - spark.createDataFrame(rdd,schema)

   ## Read file using spark

   ```
   val rdd=sc.textFile("D://cca175/data/")
   ```

   ## Rdd to Dataframe

   val df=sc.textFile("D://cca175/data/").toDF("t1") 
       df.show

   ## Method 1

   ## Create word count RDD to Dataframe

   ```
   val df=rdd.flatMap(x=>x.split(" ")).map(x=>(x,1)).reduceByKey((x,y)=>(x+y)).toDF("word","count")
   ```

   ## Method2

   ## Create Dataframe from Rdd

   ```
   val df=spark.createDataFrame(wordRdd) 
   # with header   
   val df=spark.createDataFrame(wordRdd).toDF("word","count")  df.show
   ```

   ## Method3

   ## Define Schema

   import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

   val schema=new StructType().
                       add(StructField("word",StringType,true)).
                       add(StructField("count",StringType,true))

   ## Create RowRDD

   ```
   import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
   val rowRdd=wordRdd.map(x=>(Row(x._1,x._2)))
   ```

   ## Create DataFrame from RDD with schema

   val df=spark.createDataFrame(rowRdd,schema)
   df.show

Answer (score 1):

I meet the same problem, and finally solve it. It's quite simple and easy.

1. You have to add this code  `import sc.implicits._`, `sc` means `SQLContext`. add this code you will get rdd`.toDF()` method.
2. Transform your `rdd[RawData]` to `rdd[YourCaseClass]`. For example, you have a rdd type like this `rdd[(String, Integer, Long)]`, you can create a Case Class `YourCaseClass(name: String, age: Integer, timestamp: Long)` and convert raw rdd to rdd with `YourCaseClass` type, then you get `rdd[YourCaseClass]`
3. save `rdd[YourCaseClass]` to hive table. `yourRdd.toDF().write.format("parquet").mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).insertInto(yourHiveTableName)`  Use case class to represent rdd type, we can avoid naming each column field or `StructType` related schema.

Answer (score 0):

To convert an Array[Row] to DataFrame or Dataset, the following works elegantly:

Say, schema is the StructType for the row,then

```
val rows: Array[Row]=...
implicit val encoder = RowEncoder.apply(schema)
import spark.implicits._
rows.toDS
```