# Generate a Spark StructType / Schema from a case class

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

If I wanted to create a `StructType` (i.e. a `DataFrame.schema`) out of a `case class`, is there a way to do it without creating a `DataFrame`? I can easily do:

```
case class TestCase(id: Long)
val schema = Seq[TestCase]().toDF.schema
```

But it seems overkill to actually create a `DataFrame` when all I want is the schema.

(If you are curious, the reason behind the question is that I am defining a `UserDefinedAggregateFunction`, and to do so you override a couple of methods that return `StructTypes` and I use case classes.)

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You can do it the same way [`SQLContext.createDataFrame`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/SQLContext.scala#L349) does it:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection
val schema = ScalaReflection.schemaFor[TestCase].dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType]
```

Comment: Thanks -- hadn't quite made it into `o.a.s.sql.catalyst` yet. And had I been thinking straight I would have started with `createDataFrame` just like you did. `:-(`

Comment: Sweet, you can even do `...schemaFor[(Long,Int,Long)]...`

Comment: No worries - I only found it easily because I've tried something similar myself a while ago ;) And yes - would work for any `Product`, thank you Scala!

Comment: I kind of like the `toDF` version just for terseness though

Comment: Do you know how to do an Array of type T with this approach? I tried wrapping T in another case class but it does not work as expected

Comment: Like `Encoders` in another answer, all of `org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst` is considered experimental (e.g. it isn't included in the online documentation): https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.0/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/package.scala#L21-L22

Answer (score 77):

I know this question is almost a year old but I came across it and thought others who do also might want to know that I have just learned to use this approach:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders
val mySchema = Encoders.product[MyCaseClass].schema
```

Comment: Be aware - the `Encoders` object is flagged with the `@Experimental` annotation: "An experimental user-facing API. Experimental API's might change or be removed in minor versions of Spark, or be adopted as first-class Spark API's."  Discovered that in an effort to figure out pros/cons of the different approaches (current answer vs accepted answer.)

Comment: The docs dropped experimental - probably isn't experimental any more.

Answer (score 12):

in case someone wants to do this for a custom Java bean:

```
ExpressionEncoder.javaBean(Event.class).schema().json()
```

Comment: There's also ```Encoders.bean(Event.class).schema()``` which I assume does the same.

Comment: When I use this to set the schema, I have the problem that the function above returns data members in alphabetical position while my data columns in the file are not. As it tries to match on order instead of on name, this results in corrupt data. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 5):

Instead of manually reproducing the logic for creating the implicit `Encoder` object that gets passed to `toDF`, one can use that directly (or, more precisely, implicitly in the same way as `toDF`):

```scala
// spark: SparkSession

import spark.implicits._

implicitly[Encoder[MyCaseClass]].schema
```

Unfortunately, this actually suffers from the same problem as using `org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst` or `Encoders` as in the other answers: [the `Encoder` trait](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder) is experimental.

**How does this work?** The `toDF` method on `Seq` comes from a `DatasetHolder`, which is created via the implicit [`localSeqToDatasetHolder`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SQLImplicits@localSeqToDatasetHolder[T](s:Seq[T])(implicitevidence$7:org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[T]):org.apache.spark.sql.DatasetHolder[T]) that is imported via `spark.implicits._`. That function is defined like:

```scala
implicit def localSeqToDatasetHolder[T](s: Seq[T])(implicit arg0: Encoder[T]): DatasetHolder[T]
```

As you can see, it takes an `implicit` `Encoder[T]` argument, which, for a `case class`, can be computed via [`newProductEncoder`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SQLImplicits@newProductEncoder[T<:Product](implicitevidence$8:reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[T]):org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[T]) (also imported via `spark.implicits._`). We can reproduce this implicit logic to get an `Encoder` for our case class, via the convenience [`scala.Predef.implicitly`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.12/index.html#scala.Predef$@implicitly[T](implicite:T):T) (in scope by default, because it's from `Predef`) that will just returns its requested implicit argument:

```scala
def implicitly[T](implicit e: T): T
```