# Spark schema from case class with correct nullability

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-ml, apache-spark-dataset, spark-csv

For a custom Estimator`s transformSchema method I need to be able to compare the schema of a input data frame to the schema defined in a case class. Usually this could be performed like [Generate a Spark StructType / Schema from a case class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36746055/generate-a-spark-structtype-schema-from-a-case-class) as outlined below. However, the wrong nullability is used:

The real schema of the df inferred by `spark.read.csv().as[MyClass]` might look like:

```
root
 |-- CUSTOMER_ID: integer (nullable = false)
```

And the case class:

```
case class MySchema(CUSTOMER_ID: Int)
```

To compare I use:

```
val rawSchema = ScalaReflection.schemaFor[MySchema].dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType]
  if (!rawSchema.equals(rawDf.schema))
```

Unfortunately this always yields `false`, as the new schema manually inferred from the case class is setting nullable to `true` (because ja java.Integer actually might be null)

```
root
 |-- CUSTOMER_ID: integer (nullable = true)
```

How can I specify `nullable = false` when creating the schema?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Arguably you're mixing things which don't really belong in the same space. ML Pipelines are inherently dynamic and introducing statically typed objects doesn't really change that.

Moreover schema for a class defined as:

```scala
case class MySchema(CUSTOMER_ID: Int)
```

will have not nullable `CUSTOMER_ID`. `scala.Int` is not the same as `java.lang.Integer`:

```scala
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection.schemaFor
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection.schemaFor

scala> case class MySchema(CUSTOMER_ID: Int)
defined class MySchema

scala> schemaFor[MySchema].dataType
res0: org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType = StructType(StructField(CUSTOMER_ID,IntegerType,false))
```

That being said if you want `nullable` fields `Option[Int]`:

```scala
case class MySchema(CUSTOMER_ID: Option[Int])
```

and if you want not nullable use `Int` as above.

Another problem you have here is that for `csv` every field is nullable by definition and this state is "inherited" by the encoded `Dataset`. So in practice:

```
spark.read.csv(...)
```

will always result in:

```
root
 |-- CUSTOMER_ID: integer (nullable = true)
```

and this is why you get schema mismatch. Unfortunately it is not possible to override `nullable` field for sources which don't enforce nullability constraints, like `csv` or `json`.

If having not nullable schema is a hard requirement you could try:

```scala
spark.createDataFrame(
  spark.read.csv(...).rdd,
  schemaFor[MySchema].dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType]
).as[MySchema]
```

**This approach is valid only if you know that data is actually `null` free.** Any `null` value wiil lead to runtime exception.

Comment: TL;DR: Use`Option[Int]` instead of `Int`, thanks!