# Explicitly specify schema for reading JSON and mark missing fields as null

Tags: java, json, apache-spark

I'm generating a `DataSet<Person>` like so:

```
DataSet<Person> personDs = sparkSession.read().json("people.json").as(Encoders.bean(Person.class));
```

where `Person` is

```
class Person {
    private String name;
    private String placeOfBirth;

    //Getters and setters
    ...
}
```

If my input data only contains a name (`{"name" : "bob"}`), I get an error `org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'placeOfBirth' given input columns: [name]`.

Is there any way for me to tell Spark that `placeOfBirth` (or any other field) can be `null`?

Comment: Have you tried to add second record with both - name and place of birth? This should do the trick.

Comment: Well yes, that works as expected. But my problem is that my data doesn't always have both fields (my actual bean contains about 20 fields, and input data can contain any subset of those fields; I just simplified it into a MVCE).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Spark 2.3.0 and Scala 2.11.12 that code worked for me:

```
sparkSession.read.schema("name String, placeOfBirth String").json("people.json").as(Encoders.bean(classOf[Person])).show()
```

Output:

```
+----+------------+
|name|placeOfBirth|
+----+------------+
| bob|        null|
+----+------------+
```

Comment: Thanks. This works but it's not ideal - I have to specify the schema twice - once in my bean and another time as a plaintext schema. Whilst it works, I'd much prefer a solution that doesn't require two changes if my data model changes.

Comment: I think you can use something similar as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36746055/generate-a-spark-structtype-schema-from-a-case-class) question to do it automatically

Comment: Magical, that linked answer (specifically `Encoders.bean(Person.class).schema();`) was exactly what I needed. I'll accept this an also mark my question as a duplicate.

Comment: You can do it without specifying it twice :                                                                     val schema = Encoders.bean(classOf[Person]).schema
val person = spark.read.schema(schema).json("/path/test.json"), this will give the desired result.