# How to convert an RDD into a dataframe using a user defined class and toDF

Tags: scala, apache-spark

when I try to create the following package by `sbt package`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

class Log(val cip: String, val scstatus: Int) {
    var src: String = cip
    var status: Int = scstatus
}

object IISHttpLogs {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val logFiles = "D:/temp/tests/wwwlogs" 
    val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("LogParser").getOrCreate()
    val sc = spark.sparkContext;
    sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")

    val logs = sc.textFile(logFiles)        

    import spark.implicits._
    val rowDF = logs.filter(l => !l.startsWith("#"))
        .map(l => l.split(" "))
        .map(c => new Log(c(8), c(11).trim.toInt))
        .toDF();
    println(s"line count: ${rowDF.count()}")        
    rowDF.createOrReplaceTempView("rows")
    val maxHit = spark.sql("SELECT top 1 src, count(*) FROM rows group by src order by count(*) desc")
    maxHit.show()

    spark.stop()
  }
}
```

I get the following error:

> value toDF is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Log]

I try several things like:

- toDFlog
- create a sql context and import `imlicits._` from this sqlContext

I just can't compile my code.

Any clue welcome to ovverride this error.

---

I well read [Generate a Spark StructType / Schema from a case class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36746055/generate-a-spark-structtype-schema-from-a-case-class) and write:

```
val schema =
    StructType(
        StructField("src", StringType, false) ::
        StructField("status", IntegerType, true) :: Nil)

val rowRDD = logs.filter(l => !l.startsWith("#"))
    .map(l => l.split(" "))
    .map(c => Row(c(8), c(11).trim.toInt));

val rowDF = spark.sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowRDD, schema);
```

but doing so I do not use the `Log` class. I would like to know if there is a way to get the `DataFrame` by using the defined `Log` class or if the *official/best way* is to use the `Row` class ?

for example I can't write:

```
val rowRDD = logs.filter(l => !l.startsWith("#"))
    .map(l => l.split(" "))
    .map(c => new Log(c(8), c(11).trim.toInt));
val rowDF = spark.sqlContext.createDataFrame(
    rowRDD,
    ScalaReflection.schemaFor[Log].dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType]);
```

And I just can't figure out why ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert rdd object to dataframe in spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29383578/how-to-convert-rdd-object-to-dataframe-in-spark)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a case class. At least that worked for me:

```
case class Log(cip: String,  scstatus: Int)
//...
.map(c =>  Log(c(8), c(11).trim.toInt) // ommit 'new'
.toDF()
```

I'm not quite sure whether this is a general rule. However in the announcement of the Dataset API, the usage of case classes is mentioned explicitly:

> Spark 1.6 comes with support for automatically generating encoders for a wide variety of types, including primitive types (e.g. String, Integer, Long), Scala case classes, and Java Beans.
>   (https://databricks.com/blog/2016/01/04/introducing-apache-spark-datasets.html)

If you can not use a case class, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36648128/how-to-store-custom-objects-in-dataset) seems to be appropriate.

Comment: i'm using scala 2.11.12 and even with a case class I get the same error.

Comment: did you try putting the case class inside of the ´IISHttpLogs´object?

Comment: yes, I try this also. I thonk there is an import missing or a libraryDependencies in the sbt file

Comment: in fact it seems that I haven't tried with the case class outside of the object...