# Should we parallelize a DataFrame like we parallelize a Seq before training

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-ml

Consider the code given here,

https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/ml-guide.html

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression
val training = sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
  LabeledPoint(1.0, Vectors.dense(0.0, 1.1, 0.1)),
  LabeledPoint(0.0, Vectors.dense(2.0, 1.0, -1.0)),
  LabeledPoint(0.0, Vectors.dense(2.0, 1.3, 1.0)),
  LabeledPoint(1.0, Vectors.dense(0.0, 1.2, -0.5))))

val lr = new LogisticRegression()
lr.setMaxIter(10).setRegParam(0.01)

val model1 = lr.fit(training)
```

Assuming we read "training" as a dataframe using sqlContext.read(), should
we still do something like

```
val model1 = lr.fit(sparkContext.parallelize(training)) // or some variation of this
```

or the fit function will automatically take care of parallelizing the computation/ data when passed a dataFrame

Regards,

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`DataFrame` is a distributed data structure. It is neither required nor possible to `parallelize` it. `SparkConext.parallelize` method is used only to distributed local data structures which reside in the driver memory. You shouldn't be used to distributed large datasets not to mention redistributing `RDDs` or higher level data structures (like you do in your previous question)

```
sc.parallelize(trainingData.collect())
```

If you want to convert between `RDD` / `Dataframe` (`Dataset`) use methods which are designed to do it:

1. from `DataFrame` to `RDD`:

   ```
   import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
   import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
   import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

   val df: DataFrame  = Seq(("foo", 1), ("bar", 2)).toDF("k", "v")
   val rdd: RDD[Row] = df.rdd
   ```
2. form `RDD` to `DataFrame`:

   ```
   val rdd: RDD[(String, Int)] = sc.parallelize(Seq(("foo", 1), ("bar", 2)))
   val df1: DataFrame = rdd.toDF
   // or
   val df2: DataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(rdd) // From 1.x use sqlContext
   ```

Answer (score 5):

You should maybe check out the difference between RDD and DataFrame and how to convert between the two: [Difference between DataFrame and RDD in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31508083/difference-between-dataframe-and-rdd-in-spark)

To answer your question directly: A DataFrame is already optimized for parallel execution. You do not need to do anything and you can pass it to any spark estimators fit() method directly. The parallel executions are handled in the background.