# Combined Spark output into single file

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm wondering if there's a way to combine the final result into a single file when using Spark? Here's the code I have:

```
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("logs").setMaster("local[*]")
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)

logs_1 = sc.textFile('logs/logs_1.tsv')
logs_2 = sc.textFile('logs/logs_2.tsv')

url_1 = logs_1.map(lambda line: line.split("\t")[2])
url_2 = logs_2.map(lambda line: line.split("\t")[2])

all_urls = uls_1.intersection(urls_2)
all_urls = all_urls.filter(lambda url: url != "localhost") 

all_urls.collect()

all_urls.saveAsTextFile('logs.csv')
```

The collect() method doesn't seem to be working (or I've misunderstood its purpose). Essentially, I need the 'saveAsTextFile' to output to a single file, instead of a folder with parts.

Comment: all_urls.coalesce(1).saveAsTestFile('logs.csv')

Comment: Thank you! Though I'm confused by the downvotes on my question. Is this not something worth asking, or is the Spark community just intolerant towards newbies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please find below some suggestions:

- `collect()` and `saveAsTextFile()` are actions that means they will collect the results on the driver node. Therefore is redundant to call both of them.
- In your case you just need to store the data with `saveAsTextFile()` there is no need to call `collect()`.
- `collect()` returns an array of items (in your case you are not using the returned variable)
- As Glennie and Akash suggested just use `coalesce(1)` to force one single partition. `coalesce(1)` will not cause shuffling hence is much more efficient.
- In the given code you are using the RDD API of Spark I would suggest to use dataframes/datasets instead.

Please refer on the next links for further details over RDDs and dataframes:

[Difference between DataFrame, Dataset, and RDD in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31508083/difference-between-dataframe-dataset-and-rdd-in-spark)

https://databricks.com/blog/2016/07/14/a-tale-of-three-apache-spark-apis-rdds-dataframes-and-datasets.html

Answer (score 2):

Well, before you save, you can repartition once, like below:

```
all_urls.repartition(1).saveAsTextFile(resultPath)
```

then you would get just one result file.

Comment: Or perhaps `coalesce(1)` :)

Answer (score 0):

You can store it in a `parquet` format. This is the best format suited for HDFS

```
all_urls.write.parquet("dir_name")
```