# What's the difference between RDD and Dataframe in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Hi I am relatively new to apache spark. I wanted to understand the difference between RDD,dataframe and datasets.

For example, I am pulling data from s3 bucket.

```
df=spark.read.parquet("s3://output/unattributedunattributed*")
```

In this case when I am loading data from s3, what would be RDD? Also since RDD is immutable , I can change value for df so df couldn't be rdd.

Appreciate if someone can explain the difference between RDD,dataframe and datasets.

Comment: this post explains it quite well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31508083/difference-between-dataframe-dataset-and-rdd-in-spark

Answer (score 5):

```
df=spark.read.parquet("s3://output/unattributedunattributed*")
```

With this statement, you are creating a data frame.

To create RDD use

```
df=spark.textFile("s3://output/unattributedunattributed*")
```

RDD stands for Resilient Distributed Datasets. It is Read-only partition collection of records. RDD is the fundamental data structure of Spark. It allows a programmer to perform in-memory computations

In Dataframe, data organized into named columns. For example a table in a relational database. It is an immutable distributed collection of data. DataFrame in Spark allows developers to impose a structure onto a distributed collection of data, allowing higher-level abstraction.

1. If you want to apply a map or filter to the whole dataset, use RDD
2. If you want to work on an individual column or want to perform operations/calculations on a column then use Dataframe.

for example, if you want to replace 'A' in whole data with 'B'
then RDD is useful.

```
rdd = rdd.map(lambda x: x.replace('A','B')
```

if you want to update the data type of the column, then use Dataframe.

```
dff = dff.withColumn("LastmodifiedTime_timestamp", col('LastmodifiedTime_time').cast('timestamp')
```

RDD can be converted into Dataframe and vice versa.