# import csv file in RDD PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark, rdd

We have a csv file called survey.csv and we need to load it into an rdd.

We tried this:

```
rdd_test = survey_results.csv.map(lambda x: (x, 1))
```

it doesn't work. Anyone can help?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read up on [ask], as well as [mcve]. [edit]ing the question with a sample of your CSV file (only a few rows and columns please) and elaborating on what doesn't work (is there an error, wrong/no data, something else?) would help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

`SparkContext.textFile` creates an RDD

import sys

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
 
# create Spark context
sc = SparkContext()
 
# read input text file to RDD
lines = sc.textFile("./survey.csv")
```

[Source](https://www.tutorialkart.com/apache-spark/read-input-text-file-to-rdd-example/)

[Helpful SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57566876/whats-the-difference-between-rdd-and-dataframe-in-spark)