# spark dataframe filter and select

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark scala dataframe  and need to filter the elements based on condition and select the count.

```
  val filter = df.groupBy("user").count().alias("cnt")
  val **count** = filter.filter(col("user") === ("subscriber").select("cnt")
```

The error i am facing is value select is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.Column
Also for some reasons count is **Dataset[Row]**
Any thoughts to get the count in a single line?

Comment: can you post full code along with some sample data.

Comment: how you are building df, can you post that code ?

Comment: Posting you full code will help to solve your problem, you are posting partial code thats not useful. I am not sure df is Dataframe or Dataset.

Answer (score 2):

`DataSet[Row]` is `DataFrame`

`RDD[Row]` is `DataFrame` so no need to worry.. its dataframe

see this for better understanding... [Difference between DataFrame, Dataset, and RDD in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39033308/647053)

Regarding `select is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.Column` its purely compile error.

```
 val filter = df.groupBy("user").count().alias("cnt")
  val count = filter.filter (col("user") === ("subscriber"))
    .select("cnt")
```

will work since you are missing ) braces which is closing  brace for filter.

Comment: if you are okay please care to accept [the answer as owner](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/369717) and [vote-up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400/369717)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing ")" before .select,  Please check below code.

Column class don't have .select method, you have to invoke select on Dataframe.

```
val filter = df.groupBy("user").count().alias("cnt")
  val **count** = filter.filter(col("user") === "subscriber").select("cnt")
```

Comment: Still i am getting error as type mismatch; found : org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame (which expands to) org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] required: Int

Comment: +--------+-------+
|  user  |  count|
+--------+-------+
|subscriber|267|
+--------+-------+      Filter dataframe is giving the output and this is the input for variable count     and val counts is  Dataset[Row]

Comment: For example if we have one more statement like val **count** = filter.filter(col("user") === "Consumer").select("cnt") and if we don't have data for  Consumer in filter dataframe. The spark job will fail. How to handle this scenario?

Comment: No, it will not fail. It will simply return empty dataframe.

Comment: i am trying to convert to rdd and writing to variable as below  val count = filter.filter(col("user") === "Consumer").select("cnt").rdd.map(x => x(0)).collect()(0). So my job is failing since there is no data. Any suggestions?

Comment: why are you converting to RDD, can you post your full code

Comment: If i want that count then i have convert to rdd and right?     val Consumercount = filter.filter(col("user") === "Consumer").select("cnt").rdd.map(x => x(0)).collect()(0)                     val  subscribercount = filter.filter(col("user") === "subscriber").select("cnt") .rdd.map(x => x(0)).collect()(0) . Like this i have 10 counts and all 10 have to write to 10 variables.

Comment: there are multiple ways to do that. you can check this - val Consumercount = filter.filter(col("user") === "Consumer").select("cnt").map(_.getAs[Int](0)).collect
val subscribercount = filter.filter(col("user") === "subscriber").select("cnt").map(_.getAs[Int](0)).collect
You will get result in array, then you can process

Comment: For some reason it's not accepting map(.getAs[Int](0)).collect  and it's giving error as  ◾Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset. Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing spark.implicits._ Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases.
◾not enough arguments for method map: (implicit evidence$6: org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[U])org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[U]. Unspecified value parameter evidence$6.