# Difference between type DataSet[Row] and sql.DataFrame in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am confused around 2 datatypes `DataSet[Row]` and `sql.DataFrame`. From various documents etc its mentioned that DataFrame is nothing but `DataSet[Row]`. Then what is `sql.DataFrame`.
Below is the code where i see different type returned 
Can you please explain difference between these

Below code returns of type `DataSet[Row]` (as per return type of method in intellij)

```
serverDf.select(from_json(col("value"), schema) as "event")
  .select("*")
      .filter(col("event.type").isin(eventTypes_*))
```

Below code snippet returns of type `sql.DataFrame`

```
serverDf.select(from_json(col("value"), schema) as "event")
  .select("*")
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: need full code to understand and explain also see [difference between dataset and dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39033308/3190018)

Comment: Quesion is more on sql.DataFrame vs DataSet[Row] . Seems like internally there are 2 types. i want to know the difference in that

Comment: Not sure why this is marked as duplicate since this question is about type called sql.DataFrame in scala spark code rather than DataFrame vs DataSet[Row]

Comment: sql.DataFrame and DataFrame both are same intellij prefixed with package name thats all. more over the same answer is available in another  question if you see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The are the same thing, as it is stated in the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset):

> Each Dataset also has an untyped view called a DataFrame, which is a Dataset of Row.

It's just a [type alias](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.package):

```
type DataFrame = Dataset[Row]
```

They might have different result types in intellij because of methods' different signatures.

Comment: I am talking about sql.DataFrame vs DataSet[Row] . why is there a type called sql.DataFrame is my question

Comment: @Dhatri did you check my second link? It's a `sql` package, so the type is `sql.DataFrame`.

Comment: Question is about sql.DataFrame and DataSet[Row]. Not on Dataframe vs DataSet. There are 2 types shown  in intellij. question was on that . And code is not considered in this answer.Have removed downvote though . But this is not the answer i need

Comment: @Dhatri the signatures of the methods are different because of different type aliases, that's why it's sometimes as `Dataset` and `DataFrame`

Comment: Thanks for answering . So internally sql.DataFrame and DataSet[Row] are same in the implementation? Is there a reason why filter returns DataSet[Row] vs Select ?

Comment: @Dhatri probably implementation details, but yes, they are the same, you can cast one to another

Comment: Thanks @Andronicus. So if i understand correctly in the context of Spark implementation its just a different package but same as DataSet[Row]?

Comment: @Dhatri yes, that's what I was trying to say:)