# sparkSql .registerTempTable: ERROR Table Not Found

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I had problem with registerTempTable after creating data frame.  What can be the possible reason?  Thanks.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
import sqlContext.implicits._
trainingData.registerTempTable("trainingdata")
val countResult = sqlContext.sql("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM trainingdata").collect()
```

The error message is:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Table Not Found: trainingdata
>           at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.SimpleCatalog.lookupRelation(Catalog.scala:139)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.getTable(Analyzer.scala:257)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$anonfun$apply$7.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:268)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$anonfun$apply$7.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:264)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$resolveOperators$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:57)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$resolveOperators$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:57)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:51)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperators(LogicalPlan.scala:56)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:54)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:54)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:249)

Comment: could you share the origin of your DF `trainingData` ? How and from where you get it?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a possibility that you have actually not created the `trainingData` dataframe.

You need to have a statement like the following:

- If you are reading from a Hive table

  ```
  val trainingData = sqlContext.table(s"libname.tablename")
  ```
- If you are converting a seq/array to a Dataframe

  ```
  val trainingData = Seq((1,2,3,4)).toDF("ce_sp", "ce_sp2", "ce_colour", "ce_sp3")
  ```

Here a bunch of other ways to convert RDD to DF: [How to convert rdd object to dataframe in spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29383578/how-to-convert-rdd-object-to-dataframe-in-spark)

Answer (score 0):

As per the spark version 2 and above you don't need to import implicits class and you can directly run queries something like below:

```
val sqlSeason=spark.sql("""

    select distinct a.sku,a.season,a.counter from SEASON_UPDATE2 a, 

""")

sqlSeason.createOrReplaceTempView("SEASON_UPDATE1")

sqlSeason.show()
```