# Apply Function to DataFrame Rows and Convert Back to DataFrame Spark / Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, rdd

I am having some difficulty mapping a function to rows of a dataframe and then convert this back to a new dataframe.

So far I have

```
  val intrdd = df.rdd.map(row => processRow(row))

  val processeddf = intrdd.toDF
```

However this does not work as toDF does not work for my RDD[Row] case.

Is there a good way to do this?

Note I am on Spark 2.2.0 so I cannot use SqlContext, only SparkSession.

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37011267/how-to-convert-an-rddrow-back-to-dataframe

Comment: Is there a way to do it this way with Spark 2.0.0+ and spark session? 

2) You can use createDataFrame(rowRDD: RDD[Row], schema: StructType), which is available in the SQLContext object. Example:

val df = oldDF.sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, oldDF.schema)
Note that there is no need to explicitly set any schema column. We reuse the old DF's schema, which is of StructType class and can be easily extended. However, this approach sometimes is not possible, and in some cases can be less efficient than the first one.

Comment: you can still use sqlContext in spark 2: `sparkSession.sqlContext`

Comment: val ss = SparkSession
        .builder()
        .appName("ImputationApp")
        .enableHiveSupport()
        .getOrCreate()
        
    val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(ss)

Doesn't seem to work

Comment: no, `ss.sqlContext` will give you the sqlContext

Comment: It Works. Thanks.