# How to transform using explode with custom modification to other single columns and at the same time

Tags: sql, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a data set like the following below:

```
Input Dataset

Id, Parent_id, Data
-----------------------
1, NULL, favorite: 3
2, NULL, favorite: 4
```

```
Output Dataset

Id, Parent_Id, Data
------------------------
1, NULL, favorite: 3
1_t1, 1, favorite: 3
1_t2, 1, favorite: 3
1_t3, 1, favorite: 3
2, NULL, favorite: 4
2_t1, 2, favorite: 4
2_t2, 2, favorite: 4
2_t3, 2, favorite: 4
2_t4, 2, favorite: 4
```

As you can see above that I am trying to explode the data column favorite counts property into their own individual rows and using the parent_id column to represent its root record.

So far I v tried using a Spark SQL Explode function to try to do this but however I wasn't able to get it working.

Comment: from the input it does not look like an array that can be exploded. also when you explode the parent columns i.e. Parent_ID can not be populated. -1 for not showing any coding effort.

Comment: Sure, I will add some coding snippets I have.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to generate/create new rows from the existing row by using the number from the data column and want to generate that many number of new rows with new `id` and `parent_id` pointing to the origin record

if that's the case then you can do this using `map` and `flatMap` operations as below:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

import sparkSession.sqlContext.implicits._

val input = Seq(("1", "NULL", "favorite:3"), ("2", "NULL", "favorite:4")).toDF("id", "parent_id", "data")

input.printSchema()
input.show(false)

val resultRDD = input.rdd.map(row => {
  val list = new ArrayBuffer[Row]()
  list += row

  val pointer = row.getAs[String]("data").split(":")(1).toInt

  for (index <- 1 to pointer) {
    val newId = s"${row.getAs[String]("id")}_t$index"
    list += Row.fromSeq(Seq(newId, row.getAs[String]("id"), row.getAs[String]("data")))
  }

  list
}).flatMap(_.toIterator)


val resultDF = sparkSession.createDataFrame(resultRDD, input.schema)
resultDF.show(false)
```

and the result will be:

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- parent_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- data: string (nullable = true)

+---+---------+----------+
|id |parent_id|data      |
+---+---------+----------+
|1  |NULL     |favorite:3|
|2  |NULL     |favorite:4|
+---+---------+----------+

+----+---------+----------+
|id  |parent_id|data      |
+----+---------+----------+
|1   |NULL     |favorite:3|
|1_t1|1        |favorite:3|
|1_t2|1        |favorite:3|
|1_t3|1        |favorite:3|
|2   |NULL     |favorite:4|
|2_t1|2        |favorite:4|
|2_t2|2        |favorite:4|
|2_t3|2        |favorite:4|
|2_t4|2        |favorite:4|
+----+---------+----------+
```

Comment: Would RDD work if i have a table that has 1 billion records

Comment: The problem I am having is converting it back to a dataframe. It seems like spark is complaining about encoding from a dataset to rdd to dataframe

Comment: wats the error you are getting while converting `RDD` to `DataFrame`?? Just check if you are giving the proper schema to convert the RDD into the dataframe?

Comment: this is the exact error I get --->  Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset.  Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing spark.implicits._  Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases.

Comment: I think the problem is that in your solution we are returning a dataset of type Row and my version of spark is expecting a proper type because going from dataset to rdd it needs to have way to conver and i think data set api requires a encoder configuration.

Comment: can you just check how can you convert `RDD` to a `DataFrame` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37011786/1025328) its been nicely explained

Comment: I was able to convert it using a case class and providing that to the encoder, which worked but now my spark job fails when writing to files.

Comment: you can create a new question specifying the problem that you are facing, I hope the first problem that you have mentioned is resolved by this answer if it is, then you can accept and upvote the answer. happy to help :-)