# Convert HadoopRDD to DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, apache-spark-sql

In EMR Spark, I have a HadoopRDD

```
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.DynamoDBItemWritable)] = HadoopRDD[0] at hadoopRDD
```

I want to convert this to `DataFrame org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame`.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29383578/how-to-convert-rdd-object-to-dataframe-in-spark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First convert it to simple types. Let's say your `DynamoDBItemWritable` has just one string column:

```
val simple: RDD[(String, String)] = rdd.map {
  case (text, dbwritable) => (text.toString, dbwritable.getString(0))
}
```

Then you can use `toDF` to get a DataFrame:

```
import sqlContext.implicits._
val df: DataFrame = simple.toDF()
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I run the first command to convert it to a simpler type it gives me following error: `scala> val simple: RDD[(String,String)] = orders.map {  case (text, dbwritable) => (text.toString, dbwritable.getString(0))}  
<console>:43: error: value getString is not a member of org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.DynamoDBItemWritable  
         val simple: RDD[(String,String)] = orders.map {  case (text, dbwritable) => (text.toString, dbwritable.getString(0))}`
                                                                                                                ^

Comment: [It's there in the source code.](https://github.com/Willet/Hadoop-DynamoDB/blob/7ba3df83b452e92c745c6dbc9012b9a0876756cf/src/main/java/com/willetinc/hadoop/mapreduce/dynamodb/io/DynamoDBItemWritable.java#L122) Maybe it is a different version? Anyway, just check the methods of your `DynamoDBItemWritable` and find one to read primitive types out of it.