# Convert scala FP-growth RDD output to Data frame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/mllib-frequent-pattern-mining.html#fp-growth

sample_fpgrowth.txt can be found here,
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/data/mllib/sample_fpgrowth.txt

I ran the FP-growth example in the link above in scala its working fine, but what i need is, how to convert the result which is in RDD to data frame. 
Both these RDD

```
 model.freqItemsets and 
 model.generateAssociationRules(minConfidence)
```

explain that in detail with the example given in my question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert rdd object to dataframe in spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29383578/how-to-convert-rdd-object-to-dataframe-in-spark)

Comment: I tried that i got error, might be as in am new to scala. Can u explain that in detail with the example given in my question.

Comment: @zero323 Can u help me in expaining with the example given in my question

Comment: @ArunGunalan are you sure the link you provided has the example you want to be explained?

Comment: @Ramesh Maharjan , sorry i have given a wrong link, i have edited to correct link thanks

Comment: @ArunGunalan I have answered according to what I understood

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There many ways to create a `dataframe` once you have a `rdd`. One of them is to use `.toDF` function which requires `sqlContext.implicits` library to be `imported` as

```
val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().appName("udf testings")
  .master("local")
  .config("", "")
  .getOrCreate()
val sc = sparkSession.sparkContext
val sqlContext = sparkSession.sqlContext
import sqlContext.implicits._
```

After that you read the `fpgrowth` text file and covert into an `rdd`

```
    val data = sc.textFile("path to sample_fpgrowth.txt that you have used")
    val transactions: RDD[Array[String]] = data.map(s => s.trim.split(' '))
```

I have used the code from [Frequent Pattern Mining - RDD-based API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/mllib-frequent-pattern-mining.html#fp-growth) that is provided in the question

```
val fpg = new FPGrowth()
  .setMinSupport(0.2)
  .setNumPartitions(10)
val model = fpg.run(transactions)
```

Next step would be to call `.toDF` functions

For the first `dataframe`

```
model.freqItemsets.map(itemset =>(itemset.items.mkString("[", ",", "]") , itemset.freq)).toDF("items", "freq").show(false)
```

this will result to

```
+---------+----+
|items    |freq|
+---------+----+
|[z]      |5   |
|[x]      |4   |
|[x,z]    |3   |
|[y]      |3   |
|[y,x]    |3   |
|[y,x,z]  |3   |
|[y,z]    |3   |
|[r]      |3   |
|[r,x]    |2   |
|[r,z]    |2   |
|[s]      |3   |
|[s,y]    |2   |
|[s,y,x]  |2   |
|[s,y,x,z]|2   |
|[s,y,z]  |2   |
|[s,x]    |3   |
|[s,x,z]  |2   |
|[s,z]    |2   |
|[t]      |3   |
|[t,y]    |3   |
+---------+----+
only showing top 20 rows
```

for the second `dataframe`

```
val minConfidence = 0.8
model.generateAssociationRules(minConfidence)
  .map(rule =>(rule.antecedent.mkString("[", ",", "]"), rule.consequent.mkString("[", ",", "]"), rule.confidence))
  .toDF("antecedent", "consequent", "confidence").show(false)
```

which will result to

```
+----------+----------+----------+
|antecedent|consequent|confidence|
+----------+----------+----------+
|[t,s,y]   |[x]       |1.0       |
|[t,s,y]   |[z]       |1.0       |
|[y,x,z]   |[t]       |1.0       |
|[y]       |[x]       |1.0       |
|[y]       |[z]       |1.0       |
|[y]       |[t]       |1.0       |
|[p]       |[r]       |1.0       |
|[p]       |[z]       |1.0       |
|[q,t,z]   |[y]       |1.0       |
|[q,t,z]   |[x]       |1.0       |
|[q,y]     |[x]       |1.0       |
|[q,y]     |[z]       |1.0       |
|[q,y]     |[t]       |1.0       |
|[t,s,x]   |[y]       |1.0       |
|[t,s,x]   |[z]       |1.0       |
|[q,t,y,z] |[x]       |1.0       |
|[q,t,x,z] |[y]       |1.0       |
|[q,x]     |[y]       |1.0       |
|[q,x]     |[t]       |1.0       |
|[q,x]     |[z]       |1.0       |
+----------+----------+----------+
only showing top 20 rows
```

I hope this is what you require

Comment: My pleasure @ArunGunalan :) Glad that the answer helped you