# Null values in field generates MatchError

Tags: scala, apache-spark

The following is interesting:

```
val rddSTG = sc.parallelize(
      List ( ("RTD","ANT","SOYA BEANS", "20161123", "20161123", 4000, "docid11", null, 5) , 
             ("RTD","ANT","SOYA BEANS", "20161124", "20161123", 6000, "docid11",  null, 4) ,
             ("RTD","ANT","BANANAS", "20161124", "20161123", 7000, "docid11", null, 9) ,    
             ("HAM","ANT","CORN", "20161123", "20161123", 1000, "docid22", null, 33),
             ("LIS","PAR","BARLEY", "20161123", "20161123", 11111, "docid33", null, 44)
           )
                          )

val dataframe = rddSTG.toDF("ORIG", "DEST", "PROD", "PLDEPDATE", "PLARRDATE", "PLCOST", "docid", "ACTARRDATE", "mutationseq")
dataframe.createOrReplaceTempView("STG")
spark.sql("SELECT * FROM STG ORDER BY PLDEPDATE DESC").show()
```

It generates an error as follows:

```
scala.MatchError: Null (of class scala.reflect.internal.Types$TypeRef$$anon$6)
```

As soon as I change one of the null values to non-null its works. I think I get it, in that no inference can be made on the field, but it does seem odd. Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution to yours would be to add a `test line`  as

```
val rddSTG = sc.parallelize(
  Seq ( ("RTD","ANT","SOYA BEANS", "20161123", "20161123", 4000, "docid11", null, 5) ,
    ("RTD","ANT","SOYA BEANS", "20161124", "20161123", 6000, "docid11",  null, 4) ,
    ("RTD","ANT","BANANAS", "20161124", "20161123", 7000, "docid11", null, 9) ,
    ("HAM","ANT","CORN", "20161123", "20161123", 1000, "docid22", null, 33),
    ("LIS","PAR","BARLEY", "20161123", "20161123", 11111, "docid33", null, 44),
    ("test","test","test", "test", "test", 0, "test", "", 0)
    )
    )
```

And `filter` the `test line` after `dataframe` has been created as

```
val dataframe = rddSTG.toDF("ORIG", "DEST", "PROD", "PLDEPDATE", "PLARRDATE", "PLCOST", "docid", "ACTARRDATE", "mutationseq")
                      .filter(!(col("ORIG") === "test"))
```

And you can apply your rest of the logics as

```
dataframe.createOrReplaceTempView("STG")
spark.sql("SELECT * FROM STG ORDER BY PLDEPDATE DESC").show()
```

You should have output as

```
+----+----+----------+---------+---------+------+-------+----------+-----------+
|ORIG|DEST|      PROD|PLDEPDATE|PLARRDATE|PLCOST|  docid|ACTARRDATE|mutationseq|
+----+----+----------+---------+---------+------+-------+----------+-----------+
| RTD| ANT|SOYA BEANS| 20161124| 20161123|  6000|docid11|      null|          4|
| RTD| ANT|   BANANAS| 20161124| 20161123|  7000|docid11|      null|          9|
| RTD| ANT|SOYA BEANS| 20161123| 20161123|  4000|docid11|      null|          5|
| HAM| ANT|      CORN| 20161123| 20161123|  1000|docid22|      null|         33|
| LIS| PAR|    BARLEY| 20161123| 20161123| 11111|docid33|      null|         44|
+----+----+----------+---------+---------+------+-------+----------+-----------+
```

I hope this is helpful

Answer (score 5):

The problem is - `Any` is too generic type in scala. In your case `NULL` is treated as `ANY` type.

Spark just has no idea how to serialize `NULL`.

We should explicitly provide some specific type.

Since null can't be assigned to primitive types in Scala you can use String to match the data type of the column's other values.

So try this:

```
case class Record(id: Int, name: String, score: Int, flag: String)
val sampleRdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(
  Seq(
    (1, null.asInstanceOf[String], 100, "YES"),
    (2, "RAKTOTPAL", 200, "NO"),
    (3, "BORDOLOI", 300, "YES"),
    (4, null.asInstanceOf[String], 400, "YES")))

sampleRdd.toDF("ID", "NAME", "SCORE","FLAG")
```

This way, the `df` will retain the null values.

### Other way

with `case class`

```
case class Record(id: Int, name: String, score: Int, flag: String)

val sampleRdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(
  Seq(
    Record(1, null.asInstanceOf[String], 100, "YES"),
    Record(2, "RAKTOTPAL", 200, "NO"),
    Record(3, "BORDOLOI", 300, "YES"),
    Record(4, null.asInstanceOf[String], 400, "YES")))
sampleRdd.toDF()
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure the reason behind the error but I am guessing that it is occurring because `Null` can't be a datatype of a dataframe column. Since your second last column is `null` which is part of the trait `Null`. Since they are at the bottom of the hierarchy, they can't be instantiated into any other type.
But, `null` is a subtype of everything and therefore even if you change any of those `null` to ,say, a `String`, the column becomes `String` type. This is just an assumption.

However, for your case, defining a `case class` will work.

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(List ( ("RTD","ANT","SOYA BEANS", "20161123", "20161123", 4000, "docid11", null, 5) , 
            ("RTD","ANT","SOYA BEANS", "20161124", "20161123", 6000, "docid11",  null, 4) ,
            ("RTD","ANT","BANANAS", "20161124", "20161123", 7000, "docid11", null, 9) ,    
            ("HAM","ANT","CORN", "20161123", "20161123", 1000, "docid22", null, 33),
            ("LIS","PAR","BARLEY", "20161123", "20161123", 11111, "docid33", null, 44)))
case class df_schema (ORIG: String, DEST: String, PROD: String, PLDEPDATE:String, PLARRDATE: String, PLCOSTDATE: Int, DOCID: String, ACTARRDATE: String, MUTATIONSEQ: Int)
val rddSTG = rdd.map( x=> df_schema(x._1, x._2, x._3, x._4, x._5, x._6, x._7, x._8, x._9 ) )
val dataframe = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rddSTG)
```

Comment: Adding to this answer, check this post once, https://stackoverflow.com/a/42469625/1592191

Comment: I did the class on another one. Indeed