# Cannot convert an RDD to Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I've converted a dataframe to an RDD:

```
val rows: RDD[Row] = df.orderBy($"Date").rdd
```

And now I'm trying to convert it back:

```
val df2 = spark.createDataFrame(rows)
```

But I'm getting an error:

[image]

Edit:

```
rows.toDF()
```

Also produces an error:

> Cannot resolve symbol toDF

Even though I included this line earlier:

```
import spark.implicits._
```

Full code:

```
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

import scala.util._
import org.apache.spark.mllib.rdd.RDDFunctions._
import org.apache.spark.rdd._


object Playground {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder
      .appName("Playground")
      .config("spark.master", "local")
      .getOrCreate()

    import spark.implicits._
    val sc = spark.sparkContext



    val df = spark.read.csv("D:/playground/mre.csv")
    df.show()

    val rows: RDD[Row] = df.orderBy($"Date").rdd


    val df2 = spark.createDataFrame(rows)
    rows.toDF()


  }
}
```

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez rows.toDF() also produces an error, and I've made sure that I imported spark.implicits._

Comment: BTW, are the errors real? Or just on the IDE?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert rdd object to dataframe in spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29383578/how-to-convert-rdd-object-to-dataframe-in-spark)

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I've added the relevant code and error to my question.

Comment: @user10938362 No, I've seen this question already.

Comment: @user10938362 please remove the "possible duplicate" because it's not.

Comment: Alon, could you please also add the **Spark** and **Scala** versions you are using. It may also help if you can tell us which build system you are using to compile the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your IDE is right, [SparkSession.createDataFrame](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.4/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession@createDataFrame(rdd:org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[_],beanClass:Class[_]):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) needs a second parameter: either a bean class or a schema.

This will fix your problem:

```
val df2 = spark.createDataFrame(rows, df.schema)
```