# Does Apache Spark 3 support GPU usage for Spark RDDs?

Tags: apache-spark, gpu, rdd, rapids, spark3

I am currently trying to run genomic analyses pipelines using [Hail](https://hail.is)(library for genomics analyses written in python and Scala). Recently, Apache Spark 3 was released and it supported GPU usage.

I tried [spark-rapids](https://nvidia.github.io/spark-rapids/) library start an on-premise slurm cluster with gpu nodes. I was able to initialise the cluster. However, when I tried running hail tasks, the executors keep getting killed.

On querying in Hail forum, I got the response that

> That’s a GPU code generator for Spark-SQL, and Hail doesn’t use any Spark-SQL interfaces, only the RDD interfaces.

So, does Spark3 not support GPU usage for RDD interfaces?

Comment: Apache Spark 3.0+ lets users provide a plugin that can replace the backend for SQL and DataFrame operations...Note that the plugin cannot accelerate operations that manipulate RDDs directly. See https://nvidia.github.io/spark-rapids/Getting-Started/#getting-started-with-the-rapids-accelerator-for-apache-spark for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Is there any other library or plugin which can allow manipulating RDDs directly or allow GPU usage for RDD interfaces?

Comment: If you have a gpu enabled spark, maybe you only have to change your code from rdd to dataframe. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29383578/how-to-convert-rdd-object-to-dataframe-in-spark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, spark-rapids doesn't support GPU usage for RDD interfaces.

Source: [Link](https://nvidia.github.io/spark-rapids/Getting-Started/#getting-started-with-the-rapids-accelerator-for-apache-spark)

> Apache Spark 3.0+ lets users provide a plugin that can replace the
> backend for SQL and DataFrame operations. This requires no API changes
> from the user. The plugin will replace SQL operations it supports with
> GPU accelerated versions. If an operation is not supported it will
> fall back to using the Spark CPU version. Note that the plugin cannot
> accelerate operations that manipulate RDDs directly.

Here, an answer from spark-rapids team

Source: [Link](https://github.com/NVIDIA/spark-rapids/issues/3579)

> We do not support running the RDD API on GPUs at this time. We only
> support the SQL/Dataframe API, and even then only a subset of the
> operators. This is because we are translating individual Catalyst
> operators into GPU enabled equivalent operators. I would love to be
> able to support the RDD API, but that would require us to be able to
> take arbitrary java, scala, and python code and run it on the GPU. We
> are investigating ways to try to accomplish some of this, but right
> now it is very difficult to do. That is especially true for libraries
> like Hail, which use python as an API, but the data analysis is done
> in C/C++.