# How to group unassociated content

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, hive, bigdata

I have a hive table that records user behavior

like this

| userid | behavior | timestamp | url |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | view | 1650022601 | url1 |
| 1 | click | 1650022602 | url2 |
| 1 | click | 1650022614 | url3 |
| 1 | view | 1650022617 | url4 |
| 1 | click | 1650022622 | url5 |
| 1 | view | 1650022626 | url7 |
| 2 | view | 1650022628 | url8 |
| 2 | view | 1650022631 | url9 |

About 400GB is added to the table every day.

I want to order by timestamp asc, then one 'view' is in a group between another 'view'
like this table, the first 3 lines belong to a same group , then subtract the timestamps,
like 1650022614 - 1650022601 as the view time.

How to do this?

i try lag and lead function, or scala like this

```scala
        val pairRDD: RDD[(Int, String)] = record.map(x => {
            if (StringUtil.isDateString(x.split("\\s+")(0))) {
                partition = partition + 1
                (partition, x)
            } else {
                (partition, x)
            }
        })
```

or java like this

```java
        LongAccumulator part = spark.sparkContext().longAccumulator("part");

        JavaPairRDD<Long, Row> pairRDD = spark.sql(sql).coalesce(1).javaRDD().mapToPair((PairFunction<Row, Long, Row>) row -> {
            if (row.getAs("event") == "pageview") {
                part.add(1L);
            }
        return new Tuple2<>(part.value(), row);
        });
```

but when a dataset is very large, this code just stupid.

save me plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use dataframe, you can build partition by using window that sum a column whose value is 1 when you change partition and 0 if you don't change partition.

You can transform a RDD to a dataframe with `sparkSession.createDataframe()` method as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42469625/6807769)

Back to your problem. In you case, you change partition every time column behavior is equal to "view". So we can start with this condition:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col

val df1 = df.withColumn("is_view", (col("behavior") === "view").cast("integer"))
```

You get the following dataframe:

```
+------+--------+----------+----+-------+
|userid|behavior|timestamp |url |is_view|
+------+--------+----------+----+-------+
|1     |view    |1650022601|url1|1      |
|1     |click   |1650022602|url2|0      |
|1     |click   |1650022614|url3|0      |
|1     |view    |1650022617|url4|1      |
|1     |click   |1650022622|url5|0      |
|1     |view    |1650022626|url7|1      |
|2     |view    |1650022628|url8|1      |
|2     |view    |1650022631|url9|1      |
+------+--------+----------+----+-------+
```

Then you use a window ordered by timestamp to sum over the `is_view` column:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.sum

val df2 = df1.withColumn("partition", sum("is_view").over(Window.partitionBy("userid").orderBy("timestamp")))
```

Which get you the following dataframe:

```
+------+--------+----------+----+-------+---------+
|userid|behavior|timestamp |url |is_view|partition|
+------+--------+----------+----+-------+---------+
|1     |view    |1650022601|url1|1      |1        |
|1     |click   |1650022602|url2|0      |1        |
|1     |click   |1650022614|url3|0      |1        |
|1     |view    |1650022617|url4|1      |2        |
|1     |click   |1650022622|url5|0      |2        |
|1     |view    |1650022626|url7|1      |3        |
|2     |view    |1650022628|url8|1      |1        |
|2     |view    |1650022631|url9|1      |2        |
+------+--------+----------+----+-------+---------+
```

Then, you just have to aggregate per userid and partition:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{max, min}

val result = df2.groupBy("userid", "partition")
  .agg((max("timestamp") - min("timestamp")).as("duration"))
```

And you get the following results:

```
+------+---------+--------+
|userid|partition|duration|
+------+---------+--------+
|1     |1        |13      |
|1     |2        |5       |
|1     |3        |0       |
|2     |1        |0       |
|2     |2        |0       |
+------+---------+--------+
```

The complete scala code:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, max, min, sum}

val result = df
  .withColumn("is_view", (col("behavior") === "view").cast("integer"))
  .withColumn("partition", sum("is_view").over(Window.partitionBy("userid").orderBy("timestamp")))
  .groupBy("userid", "partition")
  .agg((max("timestamp") - min("timestamp")).as("duration"))
```

Comment: I'm not used to using Query DSL,  but I was inspired by this answer,  I solved by SparkSQL like this 
`select userid,
    url,
    timestamp,
    sum(case behavior when 'view' then 1 else 0 end) 
        over(partition by userid 
             order by timestamp asc
             rows between unbounded preceding and current row
        ) as partitioner 
from tmp_table`

again thanks a lot