# Spark: Save single, ordered file with header

Tags: apache-spark

Given a sorted `RDD[String]`, how can I save it to file with a header?

```
val header: String = "header row"
val foo: RDD[(Int, String)] = ???
foo.coalesce(1).sortByKey().saveAsTextFile("//some/path")
```

This should save the data in order (I believe). How can I inject the header in the top line?

Comment: What do you mean by "with a header"?
column name?

Comment: No, just header info. It's not a CSV. The format is Metis input, which requires the first line to be a summary of the remaining data.

Comment: For a similar question sean-owen suggested creating RDD for the header line, and performing union between both RDDs (header and original-RDD)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26157456/add-a-header-before-text-file-on-save-in-spark